# Desktop environment isn't working after trying to install GNOME 40

Tags: apt, gnome, desktop-environments, add-apt-repository, gnome-session

I have installed Ubuntu 21.04 on my Laptop, everything with the DE was fine till now.
I saw a video on YouTube showing the new Gnome 41. I wanted to install that.
I didn't found a tutorial to install that one but I found one for Gnome 40. So I thought I could install that and then upgrade it.
After following [this](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2021/04/how-to-install-gnome-40-on-ubuntu-2104.html) Tutorial, my system corrupted. That means that when I start it up, it only shows a sad emoji with the text Oh no! Something went wrong. A problem has occurred and the system can't recover. Please contact a system administrator.
This happened after I typed

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:shemgp/gnome-40
```

and pressed enter to install it and then installed gnome-session like it recommended it in the page that the above command showed like this:

```
sudo apt install gnome-session -y
```

after that I Logged out and got that screen like I described earlier.
I am able to go into my console by pressing Ctrl+Alt+F5 and then I tried uninstalling the gnome-session thing with:

```
sudo apt remove gnome-session
```

I also tried to to remove the repository, but there it was just more trial in error:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:shemgp/gnome-40
```

I don't even know if this command existr like that
Hope you can help me ASAP and if you need more info, just say it. I could also share the command history if you want to.
Output of

```
grep -ir MasterSoft24 /etc/apt --include="*.list"
```

is

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/home:MasterSoft24.list:deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/MasterSoft24/xUbuntu_20.10/ /
```

Answer (score 1):

Removing repository with `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:shemgp/gnome-40` will not downgrade the packages to their stock versions.

You have to use `ppa-purge` instead.

So you have to re-add the problematic [PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eshemgp/+archive/ubuntu/gnome-40) by

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:shemgp/gnome-40
```

then install `ppa-purge` by

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

and finally revert all GNOME packages to their official versions using

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:shemgp/gnome-40
```

Then reboot.

Comment: When I do this I get the Error 
W:GPG error: <link> InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 54E795FB12ECE9A9 home:MasterSoft24 OBS Project 
E:The repository <link> In Release is not signed
Warning apt-get update failed for some reason
But I also tried to install gnome-session again in the meantime, which said that it needs older versions of gnome-session-bin and common, from which I looked up the version with apt-cache and removed the versions 40.1.1-0ubuntu3 and then reinstalled gnome-session. Maybe that's why it's still not working btw I don't get the Error Screen now

Comment: You have to correct your repositories and GPG keys. The downgrade process can't be run when they are broken. Please add output of `grep -ir MasterSoft24 /etc/apt --include="*.list"` to the question.

Comment: Or try to run `wget -q https://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:MasterSoft24/xUbuntu_20.10/Release.key -O- | sudo apt-key add -` directly.  Then run `sudo apt-get update` and ensure that you do not have errors anymore.

Comment: I still got the errors after doing the wget command. But while doing the wget command I got the Error:  Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key(8)).

Comment: This is a warning. Please be more accurate. Please upload full output of `sudo apt-get update` to the pastebin.

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/STMkdPZ1

Comment: sorry if I didn't tag you in the other comment, I forgot... @N0rbert

Comment: Please run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 
 54E795FB12ECE9A9` and then retry with `sudo apt-get update`.

Comment: ran it, first the output while running the first then the update, I copied everything so my name "kimil" is in the pastebin as well as the pcname etc. https://pastebin.com/p7XH7Mpt hope you'll help me further! @N0rbert

Comment: You have to remove MasterSoft24 repository's *.list file and then retry.

Comment: Which list file? @N0rbert

Comment: OK i think I got it, I did the first command int the pastebin to remove the list file then the other commands again and this is the output. https://pastebin.com/H4eFVWqk  @N0rbert